# Equivalence of norms on Banach space of 2nd-degree polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $ E = \left \{ p(x) = a + bx^2 \right \} \subseteq (C([0,1]), d_{\infty}) $, where $d_{\infty}$ is the distance induced by the uniform norm $\|p\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |p(x)|$. I have proved already that $E$ is closed and thus complete.

We now define  $\|p \|_{E} = |p(0)| + |p'(1)|$, which I have shown to be a valid norm on $E$. The question asks to show that $\|p\|_{\infty}$ and $\|p\|_{E}$ are equivalent. I was able to show that $\|p\|_{E} \geq \|p\|_{\infty}$. However, I cannot find a constant $ C>0$ such that $\|p\|_{E} \leq C\|p\|_{\infty}$.

I know that such a constant must exist because all norms on finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent. How can $C$ be constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||p||_E =|p(0)|+|p'(1)| \leq ||p||_\infty+|2b|=||p||_\infty+|2b+2a-2a|\leq ||p||_\infty+|2b+2a|+|2a| =||p||_\infty+2|p(1)|+2|a|=\leq||p||_\infty+2||p||_\infty+2|p(0)|
\leq ||p||_\infty+2||p||_\infty+2||p||_\infty=5||p||_\infty$

Comment: Thank you! I'm ashamed I didn't see this